# UIView horizontal animation not horizontal

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uiview

I have a UIView whose dimensions are (x: 16, y: 360, w: 369, h: 81) and I want to hide it with a UIAction by just sending it out of the screen. So I did `UIView.animateWithDuration(0.2, animations: {self.View.frame = CGRectMake(x: -410, y: 360, 369, 81)})`, the ideal animation would be to have it slide out along the y-axis, however what I am getting now is the view going down and left (instead of just left). I'm kinda confused since I kept the 'y' the same in animation.

Answer (score 0):

You are moving the view of the view controller NOT the view that you want to move (note self.view ...):

```
self.View.frame = CGRectMake(x: -410, y: 360, 369, 81)
```

Comment: sorry, View is the name of my uiview, which is an IBOutlet to the view controller

Comment: I mean I can change it to something else, but it is still going to do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem, because I embedded my view in a navigation controller, the header is probably screwing with my coordinates, so I used `frame.origin.x` and `frame.origin.y` instead.